# Script to generate Xcode empty project

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode

I always need some empty Xcode projects for testing purposes. (I cannot use coderunner or other stuff, I really need an Xcode project).

I tried different approaches but I didn't find a real solution:

1. Created a basic, empty project and created a script for copying the entire folder.

It works, but you cannot have different names for the project, this means that you have to rename the project manually after the copy.

2. Using the Crafter gem

It's a useful gem, but you can only configure an existing project, you cannot create a new one.

3. Using KZBootstrap

The same as before, it's useful for configuring the project, not for creating a new one.

4. Using the xcodeproj gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/xcodeproj)

The documentation is not enough for me, and I don't understand how to use it :(

Any advice?

Comment: who downvoted the question should add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution that fits my needs.
I started with an empty, sample project (here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/792862/SamplePRJ.zip)
 and i wrote a bash script to rename all the files and all the occurrences of the previous name.

The script can be improved, but it basically works

```
export LC_CTYPE=C
export LANG=C

OLDNAME="SamplePRJ"
NEWNAME="Sample2PRJ"

mv $OLDNAME $NEWNAME
cd $NEWNAME

mv $OLDNAME $NEWNAME
mv ${OLDNAME}Tests ${NEWNAME}Tests
mv ${OLDNAME}.xcodeproj ${NEWNAME}.xcodeproj

mv ${NEWNAME}.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/${OLDNAME}.xcscheme ${NEWNAME}.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/${NEWNAME}.xcscheme

find . -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' "s/${OLDNAME}/${NEWNAME}/g"
```